# Create a xml which has preferred namespace prefixs and a namespace without prefix Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, jaxb, eclipselink

I have tried this using JAXB's implementations eclipse.persistence.Moxy and glassfish.JAXB. I have found the solution for Preferred namespaces(By @XmlScama annotation and NamespacePrefixMapper implementation) but I am getting a  problem in a namespace without a prefix. It always appends the default prefix. I want to generate the following XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetPatientFullMedicationHistory6 xmlns="https://secure.newcropaccounts.com/V7/webservices">
      <credentials>
        <PartnerName>string</PartnerName>
        <Name>string</Name>
        <Password>string</Password>
      </credentials>
      <accountRequest>
        <AccountId>string</AccountId>
        <SiteId>string</SiteId>
      </accountRequest>
      <patientRequest>
        <PatientId>string</PatientId>
      </patientRequest>
      <prescriptionHistoryRequest>
        <StartHistory>dateTime</StartHistory>
        <EndHistory>dateTime</EndHistory>
        <PrescriptionStatus>string</PrescriptionStatus>
        <PrescriptionSubStatus>string</PrescriptionSubStatus>
        <PrescriptionArchiveStatus>string</PrescriptionArchiveStatus>
      </prescriptionHistoryRequest>
      <patientInformationRequester>
        <UserType>string</UserType>
        <UserId>string</UserId>
      </patientInformationRequester>
      <patientIdType>string</patientIdType>
      <includeSchema>string</includeSchema>
    </GetPatientFullMedicationHistory6>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The XML generated after All the efforts are

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap12='http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope'>
    <soap12:Body>
        <GetPatientFullMedicationHistory6 xmlns:ns2='https://secure.newcropaccounts.com/V7/webservices'>
            <credentials>
                <PartnerName>demo</PartnerName>
                <Name>demo</Name>
                <Password>demo</Password>
            </credentials>
            <accountRequest>
                <AccountId>demo</AccountId>
                <SiteId>demo</SiteId>
            </accountRequest>
            <patientRequest>
                <PatientId>DEMOPT1</PatientId>
            </patientRequest>
            <prescriptionHistoryRequest>
                <StartHistory>2004-01-01T00:00:00.000</StartHistory>
                <EndHistory>2012-01-01T00:00:00.000</EndHistory>
                <PrescriptionStatus>C</PrescriptionStatus>
                <PrescriptionSubStatus>%</PrescriptionSubStatus>
                <PrescriptionArchiveStatus>N</PrescriptionArchiveStatus>
            </prescriptionHistoryRequest>
        </GetPatientFullMedicationHistory6>
    </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "GetPatientFullMedicationHistory6"
})
public class Body {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private GetPatientFullMedicationHistory6 GetPatientFullMedicationHistory6;
```

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "credentials",
    "accountRequest",
    "patientRequest",
    "prescriptionHistoryRequest",
    "patientInformationRequester",
    "patientIdType",
    "includeSchema",
    "xmlns"
})
public class GetPatientFullMedicationHistory6 {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private Credentials credentials;

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private AccountRequest accountRequest;

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private PatientRequest patientRequest;

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private PrescriptionHistoryRequest prescriptionHistoryRequest;

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private PatientInformationRequester patientInformationRequester;

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private String patientIdType;

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private String includeSchema;

    @XmlAttribute(required = true, namespace = "https://secure.newcropaccounts.com/V7/webservices")
    private String xmlns = "https://secure.newcropaccounts.com/V7/webservices";
```

Comment: Hi yparikh102, welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66363511/edit) your question and provide also the actual output from JAXB and the relevant part of the generating code? Are all those XML elements qualified or are there elements without a namespace?

Comment: Without the adnotated class `GetPatientFullMedicationHistory6` it is difficult to tell what went wrong.